# What was Megatron's Cybertronian Alt-Mode?

Tags: transformers

In both the G1 Cartoon and Marvel continuities, the Cybertronians developed the ability to transform in the early days of the war (in the show, the Autobots did it first; in the comics, the Decepticons did it first).

During the show, we see the Cybertronian Alt-Modes for some of the Cybertronians, but neither the show, or the comics (as far as I can find) ever mention or show what Megatron's Alt-Mode was prior to re-awakening on Earth and acquiring the new Walther P38 mode.

What was Megatron's original Cybertronian Alt-Mode in the G1 continuity?

Comment: Wikipedia says that his alt's include a cybertronian jet and various non-human vehicles; http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Megatron

Comment: @Richard The live-action and Prime/Aligned continuities both had him as a Cybertronian jet. G2 was a tank.

Comment: I'm not sure if it was ever seen. In G1 comic issue #1, Megatron is always shown in humanoid form. Given the importance of Megatron's firepower (according to issue #1 his fusion cannon could lay waste to entire cities) it seems likely that his alt-mode was a tank or gun - or like Galvatron he was a triple changer and could transform into either!

Answer (score 1):

There is no official Cybertronian alt mode for G1 Megatron, but that hasn't stopped some fans from creating their own interpretations. This one by Deviantart user Guidoguidi is my favorite: [image: Megatron in cannon form]

Comment: Is it official that there's no Alt-Mode for Megatron?